# WCF service library "Fire and forget" from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a WCF Service library and added built  .dll as reference in my web application (asp.net).

I tried IsOneWay=true as well but looks like it's not working.

I was trying "Fire and Forget" from web application and put some 10 seconds sleep in my service method to test it. But my web app waits for 10 seconds on button click. 
Please guide what and where I might be doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Web app Button click:

```
 EmailAndSync.Service1 svc = new Service1();
 svc.saveData();
```

Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
         void saveData();
    }

public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void saveData()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            sendUsersMail("sak_user@domain.com");
        }
        protected void sendUsersMail(string emailid)
        {
        //stuff
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Delegate to call the service and that worked smoothly.

Web app code:

```
public delegate void Worker();
Worker newthread;

//on button click
 newthread = new Worker(callmethod);
 newthread.BeginInvoke(null, null);

 protected void callmethod()
    {
        EmailAndSync.Service1 svc = new Service1();
        svc.saveData(0);
        newthread.EndInvoke(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`[OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]` for methods that return void or not

[MSDN - How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx)

The event-driven asynchronous calling model is not supported when using a ChannelFactory. See
[How to: Call Operations Asynchronously Using a Channel Factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132(v=vs.110).aspx)